# API post not decting raw json model

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, postman

once again, I'm trying to hit post method of controller but the method is not catching json model. rest, all types of headers are working instead of json post.

[image]

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    readonly string CorsPolicy = "MyPolicy";

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add Cors
        services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy(CorsPolicy, builder =>
        {
            builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                   .AllowAnyMethod()
                   .AllowAnyHeader();
        }));

        services.AddControllersWithViews();

    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseCors(CorsPolicy);

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

[image]

Can anyone please guide me on what should I need to change?
or where am I wrong in this?

Comment: Red squiggly lines should give it away as well... that is not correct json... property names need to be quoted.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to share a [mcve] -- specifically the JSON you are sending, and the c# data model `Department` to which you are trying to bind the JSON as **text** rather than as a screenshot.  On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you are using json , you have to add [FromBody] to the action

```
pubic ActionResult Post([FromBody] department)
```

also fix json in postman

```
{
    "DepartmentId": 0,
    "DepartmentName": "bpu"
}
```

also to support no sensitive letter case add these options to startup

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;
.....

services.AddControllersWithViews()
    .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
           options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver =
              new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver());
```

Answer (score 1):

Try matching case of field name, and include quotes, e.g. `"DepartmentId": 0`

And confirm request has `Content-Type: application/json`

Comment: Nope... Still not working